# how to assign default value in object destructuring?

Tags: javascript

```js
const myArray = {
     "valueA":""
     "valueB":"BB"
    }
   let {valueA:A="E"} = myArray;
   let {valueB:B} = myArray
   console.log(A) // is empty need to show default value "E"
   console.log(A) // BB
```

Here I need to show default value E if it is empty

Comment: It's just a hack but you can try this:

`let { valueA: A = "E" } = { ...myArray, valueA: myArray.valueA || undefined };`

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible in your case since you have empty string as value (as mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#default_value)),

> Each destructured property can have a default value. The default value is used when the property **is not present**, or has value **undefined**.

But the below case would work, since `valueC` doesn't exist (i.e. it is `undefined`).

```js
const myArray = {
 "valueA":"",
 "valueB":"BB"
}

let {valueC: A = "E"} = myArray;
let {valueB: B} = myArray;
console.log(A) 
console.log(B)
```